# Single phase transformer circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, electromagnetic

A single-phase transformer with a rating of 50 kVA, 2300/230 V, 50 Hz, has the following resistances and reactances (the primary is the side with the lower voltage):

[image]

The transformer supplies a load of 40 kVA with a power factor of 0.8 lagging at a voltage of 2300 V through a 1 km long line with a total impedance (phase and neutral) of Zl = 1 + j0.5 Ω. I need to know the voltage that should be applied to the primary of the transformer, the current absorbed by it, and the power factor at which it operates.

Shoudn't the applied voltage be 230v? Since it is said that the voltage applied to the load is 2300V (i am assuming that corresponds to the voltage of the secondary) and the voltage relation is 2300/230.

I did a scheme of the circuit with the transfomer, and then the scheme of the equivalent circuit diagram refered to the secondary. (2nd picture)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCbXU4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since a=Vp/Vs  --> a = 10

To the equivalent diagram refered to the secondary, i used the following values:

- R'p = Rp * 10^2
- X'p = Xp * 10^2
- R'fe = Rfe * 10^2
- X'm = Xm * 10^2

I also calculated the current going through the secondary by using the power: P = V * I --> I = 40K/2300.

I don't really know what to do from here. I don't understand how i am supposed to use the Rfe and Xm.

Comment: Why is the magnetization reactance shown on the secondary side column in your table? Why does your first diagram translate 43.7 ohms to 43.7 henries? In fact why are you converting ohms to henries on all the inductances?

Comment: The circuit lab only allowed me to put inductors represented in Henrys. I put a note on the diagram saying to assume Henrys are Ohms.

Comment: Also i assumed that the fact that the magnetization reactance is in the secondary side is just a way of disposing the values on the table

Comment: OK, a mistake I see is that when you transferred impedances from the secondary side to the primary side you mistakenly multiplied by 10 when you should have multiplied by the turn-ratio squared i.e. 100.

Comment: However, it's unclear whether you should have divided by 100 because I'm not sure which side is the 2300 volt side and which side is the 230 volt side. Maybe you should post an image of the whole question.

Comment: I just realized i said i refered to the primary, i meant the secondary. Also, in the question is mentioned that the primary is the side with lower voltage. So i'm assuming the primary has 230v. For that reason i am multiplying for 100 instead of dividing.

Comment: To feed a transformer with 230 V and 50 kVA over a 1 km long line does not make sense. More than 217 A. With 2300 V only 21.7 A would be needed.

Comment: I think you need to grasp the nettle and properly rewrite this question incorporating all the facts that have come to light. That doesn't mean raising a new question. Let me know when you have done this please.

Comment: The first 2 paragraphs are exacly what is said on the question. I don't really know how i can clarify this to you. Are you saying that maybe the question itself is wrong? @Andyaka